# supporting both \"u and ü

Tags: plain-tex, accents

I maintain [`musixtex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/musixtex) extension package [musixtmr.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/musixtex/tex/musixtmr.tex) that enables times text fonts. I thought I could enable accented glyphs like `ü` by
using ptmr8r instead of ptmr7t.  But this has the effect of disabling traditional commands such as `\"u` found in legacy documents.  Is there a package that will allow me to support both traditional and modern accented characters? etex is the processing engine used for `musixtex` documents.

Comment: when you switch encodings you need to redefine all the accent commands such as `\"` to use the new encoding number for the accent, and to make it use the pre-composed characters when available. latex does this automatically so you could use the code from there if you must use plain.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  I "could use the code from there" if I had sufficient TeXpertise even to _find_ the relevant code.

Comment: Looking at your file: don't mix 8r and 8t fonts. These are different encodings. Stick to 8t.

Comment: @BobTennent You should be clearer about what input encodings you expect in documents: the solution is very different for Latin-1 and UTF-8.

Comment: The documents that use \" are old scores, almost certainly latin1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are saving the file in latin-1 then the following highly simplified definitions will let you input the latex accent file, which will work for those characters that are the same in latin1 and T1 (8t) encoding.

An alternative would be to use the tcx encoding definition possibilities provided by the engine if you use the `--enc` command line option, but either way using a format designed for use with non-ascii characters would seem more reasonable, really.

[image]

```
\font\zz=ptmr7t at 12pt

\zz aaa \"u bbb ü

\def\ProvidesFile#1[#2]{}
\def\DeclareFontEncoding#1#2#3{}
\def\DeclareTextAccent#1#2#3{%
\def#1##1{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname T1\string#1-\string##1\endcsname\relax
{\accent#1 ##1}%
\else
\csname T1\string#1-\string##1\expandafter\endcsname
\fi}}
\def\DeclareTextCommand#1#2{\xdtcmd}%not today
\def\xdtcmd#1#{\xxdtcmd}%not today
\def\xxdtcmd#1{}%not today
\def\DeclareTextCompositeCommand#1#2#3#4{}%not today
\def\DeclareTextSymbol#1#2#3{%
\def#1{\char#3\relax}}
\def\DeclareTextComposite#1#2#3#4{%
\expandafter\def\csname T1\string#1-\string#3\endcsname{\char#4\relax}}

\input t1enc.def
\font\zz=ptmr8t at 12pt

\zz aaa \"u bbb ü

\bye
```

Comment: latex is also used when there are musical excerpts; what is the appropriate conditional to use to test whether latex or etex is the processor?

Comment: @BobTennent latex is a macro format and etex is a tex engine, so the test is really latex or plain tex, perhaps `\ifx\documentclass\undefined plain \else latex\fi` but it depends on the context, normally you need to know anyway as all the user level commands are different so testing within a document isn't normally required.

Comment: the "extension" file in question is used for scores in both TeX and  LaTeX.